# Connect to ldap with ldapsearch

Tags: java, unix, ldap, aix

I need help on a job issue.

We are on AIX VM and we've got a Java script based on Java class `fr.restitx.LDAP.LDAPSample` (AIX class I guess) which connects and collects data from an LDAP. We need to optimize this script because it lasts 1h30. So I decided to go with `ldapsearch` command whereas I don't know how the connection currently work.

I already tried :

```
ldapsearch -h ldaps://url.dc1.dc2:port -D 'uid=my-user,ou=ex,ou,ex2,dc=dc1,dc=dc2'-w 'pass' -b 'dc=dc1,dc=dc2' -s sub '(objectClass=user)'
```

This command doesn't work and throws:

```
ldap_simple_bind: Unknown error
ldap_search_ext: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Do you have some ideas to propose for test please?

Comment: truss is the first debug tool you could try, but it isn't trivial to use either, you should ask a competent AIX-user for help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the command you have listed:

```
ldapsearch -h ldaps://url.dc1.dc2:port ...
```

I strongly suspect you need to replace 'port' with the port number your ldap server is listening on.